# How to keep log of all users who are visiting site or page on site Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

We have sharepoint site and we are using sharepoint 2007.
We want to keep track of all users who are accessing the site and pages of the site.
We are checking sharepoin site usage report but we are getting some unexpected results.
Is there any alternate solution(or programatically) we can use to find out the users log?
Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 2):

3rd Party Products: [DocAve Auditor](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-auditing-docave/), [Invenio Audit Module](http://www.invenioworks.com/) & [Varonis](http://www.varonis.com/solutions/by-role/sharepoint.html) or you could go the code route and look at the [Microsoft Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or just roll your own HTTP Module to trap requests.

Answer (score 0):

Or roll your own Google Analytics-esque client side script. We made our own, only to keep our stuff inside the firewall. You could parse IIS logs as well, but that kind of data requires some analysis to be accurate (i.e., limiting only to get requests on aspx pages, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar requirement in sharepoint 2016, We were able to get the user details from IIS logs, IIS log has the user ID , site URL , date and many other details.

Once you get the IIS logs you can use log parser tool (The tool is very powerful I could parse logs which were almost 100 GB) to parse the logs and then export the data to a csv file which can be then imported into SQL database and you can run queries on the data.

Log parser is a command line tool, you could even automate it if needed.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24659

alternate solution is, you could use Splunk and export the IIS logs to splunk, and then created a splunk dashboard to view all the details.